# Java error on startup when try to run .exefile

Tags: java, exe, startup

I wrote a simple addition program in java and have made it into a .exe file. But when I try to run the exe file, even by clicking on it from my desktop, I get the error "An error has occured during startup:" with this giant thing:

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
at addit.main(addit.java:15)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
```

My manifest files contains:

"Main-Class: addit

"

It has the proper two lines

The addit.java program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class addit
{
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;

System.out.println("Welcome to Addit!");

System.out.println("Please enter the first digit.");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
x = scanner.nextInt();

System.out.println("Please enter the second digit.");
y = scanner.nextInt();

z = x + y;

System.out.println("The sum of " + x + " and " + y + " is " + z);
  }
}
```

Also, just by the way, the program compiles and runs fine, even when run through the cmd (when I run addit.java).

EDIT: Oh, wait, I'm sorry, it turns out the addit.exe isn't running correctly. I'm sorry, I must have been confusing.. ><

Comment: post your manifest file content

Comment: there must be an empty line at the end of file

Comment: Could you post the addit class?

Comment: You have a problem in your code at line 15. Can you show it to us ? you probably have done one iteration too many in a loop

Comment: Does there have to be a space? I just hit enter twice

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. I wrote the program in DrJAVA and then made it into a jar in the cmd

Comment: What command are you using to build the jar and run it? It works for me with your manifest file.

Comment: And what Java are you using? (run `java -version`)

Comment: I entered `jar cfm addit.jar manifest.txt addit.class` into the cmd to make it into a jar

Comment: What command are you using to run it?

Comment: I was using `java -jar addit.jar` But it's working now...

Comment: I'm sorry, I was confusing myself. It turns out the addit.exe file is giving me that error and not running properly

Comment: [vinz243](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2533082/vinz243) asks: How did you export it ? Runnable jar with eclipse?

Comment: I made the .exe file using exe4j (jar to exe)

Comment: Is it possible that the .exe file does not work properly because there is no GUI? So it won't show anything so it just gives the error?

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me. Make sure you're running the jar this way

```
java -jar addit.jar
```

*Input*

```
1 2
```

***EDIT** : (try this with addit.exe)*

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter the first digit: ");
x = scanner.nextInt();

scanner.nextLine(); // skips '\n' causing the problem

System.out.println("Please enter the second digit: ");
y = scanner.nextInt();

z = x + y;
```

Comment: why are you passing arguments?

Comment: A space is required between the inputs because it's the default delimiter for Scanner. @user1569574 Can you please try again and let me know?

Comment: When I enter "1 2" on the same line in the cmd, it asks for the second digit but then did report the sum. But it's okay, the jar file works

Comment: I made the .exe file with this code, but I still got the same error as in my initial post

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming from line `15`

```
at addit.main(addit.java:15)
```

Look at your code on line `15`

```
x = scanner.nextInt();
```

At this point your program trying to read an integer value from console as

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

`scanner` is set to read the input from the `System.in` which is by default the console of the OS. But, as your are running your program out of the box so your program not getting where from read the input.

Rewrite your program and put hardcoded values instead reading from user. Then do all this stuff. If works, you will get your answer.